# Compute Derivative in Polar Coordinates

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

I have the function 
$$\phi(r)=-192r^5+480r^4-440r^3$$ with $1/4\leq r\leq 3/4,$ in polar coordinates. So $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$ I want to compute $\phi'(r)$ and $\phi''(r).$ So, I use the chain rule,
$$\frac{d\phi}{dr}=\frac{d\phi}{dx}\frac{dx}{dr}+\frac{d\phi}{dy}\frac{dy}{dr}$$
for the first derivative. And the same technique for the second derivative. I am right?

Comment: Since you can write $\phi$ explicitly as a function of $r$, then this is just simple differentiation of a polynomial. (I'm assuming that $\phi'$ means $d\phi/dr$ here)

Comment: No.$\phi'(r)=960r^4+1920r^3-..

Comment: @MPW and then define $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$?

Comment: @ChrisPerv : Why bring $x$ and $y$ into it? They aren't in your original definition of the function to be differentiated. Maybe you are omitting some details of what the problem actually is?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution. Because $r=r(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ then
$$\phi'(r)=\frac{d\phi}{dr}=\frac{d\phi}{dx}\frac{dx}{dr}+\frac{d\phi}{dy}\frac{dy}{dr}$$
and for the second derivative we must use chain rule again, so
$$\phi''(r)=\frac{d^2\phi}{dr^2}=\frac{d}{dr}\left(\frac{d\phi}{dr}\right)=\frac{d}{dr}\left(\frac{d\phi}{dx}\frac{dx}{dr}+\frac{d\phi}{dy}\frac{dy}{dr}\right)=\cdots=$$
$$=\cdots=\phi_x\frac{d^2x}{dr^2}+\phi_y\frac{d^2y}{dr^2}+\phi_{xx}\left(\frac{dx}{dr}\right)^2+2\phi_{xy}\left(\frac{dx}{dr}\right)\left(\frac{dy}{dr}\right)+\phi_{yy}\left(\frac{dy}{dr}\right)^2$$

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as you don't know the dependency of $\phi$ over $x,y$.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to bring in x or y nor domain of $r$.

Just differentiate $\phi$ two times w.r.t. $r.$